# Removing Reactjs Om components (ClojureScript)

Tags: javascript, clojure, reactjs, clojurescript, om

I am trying to make a tabbed windowing system within a webpage using om-bootstrap's "pills" navigation by adding tabs when links get clicked and removing tabs when an X button on the tabs is clicked.

I need to know how to add and remove data from the global state/store and create a macro that can be used to declare a tab app component and make it remove itself when it is no longer alive.

What is the best way to reference the global state? **How can I make a component remove/unmount itself when it gets closed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since removal of a subcomponent affects its owner, you should let the owner (i. e. the "tab system") know that this tab needs to be closed/destroyed/obliterated.

I've digged through [`todomvc` example](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc) ([live](http://swannodette.github.io/todomvc/labs/architecture-examples/om/)) assuming your process of destroying tab panes is pretty much the same as destruction of TODO items there. I see nothing ocnflicting so far. Here are my findings:

1. [**A channel is used...**](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/app.cljs#L133). When application starts (`IWillMount`), a `(chan)` (from `core.async`) is written into application state at `:comm` key.
2. [**...for event handling...**](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/app.cljs#L135). Events from the channel are handled in the loop following that code, in `go`-form, asynchronously with the block it appears in (with `<!` being a "kinda blocking" operation). *Well, you may know it, I didn't, still learning what is CLJS all about.*
3. [**...that is passed to all child items' init states...**](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/app.cljs#L54). So it becomes a way for children to send events to the root. *I'm starting to like this.*
4. [**...so they can send events to their parent!**](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/item.cljs#L62) This is done in `put!` calls with the `comm` channel, fetched in the linked line. Events put there are handled by the loop defined in (2), which delegates them to appropriate functions depending on `type` (accompanying keyword).

*I'm nowhere near a ClojureScript pro, but I'm learning. So if the above doesn't make sense, this is normal and means I didn't understand something. If that turns out to be the case, putting me back on track would be much appreciated.*

Comment: That is a great example of removing components and communication - clearly components are being destroyed. However, you have only explained the communication. It seems much more complex operations are at play. Take a look at [util.cljs](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/utils.cljs), it includes goog.ui IdGenerator into a guid function used in [app.cljs](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/app.cljs#L94).

Comment: @user2491 I fail to see the relevance of this to component removal. On top of that, `(guid)` is only used once outside of benchmarks and it does what its name says.

Comment: You may be right as I am not an expert by any means either, but it seems core.async is not necessary at all for component removal and that it is actually done [here](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/app.cljs#L142) somehow by adding and removing unique ids for each child-component. For example, I should be able to have "delete random child" button on the parent and not have any communication

Comment: @user2491 No, not for removal. I was looking at how a child can self-destruct. Best I could think of is telling the parent "kill me", TODOMVC uses a channel for that. And the parent does that [here](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/app.cljs#L103). `om/transact!` is defined [here](https://github.com/omcljs/om/blob/245d5b0a5837593e412f31c1eb2ac376b8ffa7b7/src/om/core.cljs#L1224): just modifies the state tree and triggers a re-render.

Comment: `tag` seems to be just a "unique transaction key" and only contains descriptive information on what it does. No ides what is it for, but it seems to not be compulsory.